# osx Captive Portal with USB to Ethernet adapter

Tags: network, wifi, usb, ethernet

I am trying to get the Captive Portal working on Mac osx. When using wifi to connect to my server, I get the expected wispr request to  http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html - however, using an USB to Ethernet adapter, I only receive requests for http://init-p01st.push.apple.com/bag on my machine on the other side of the USB to Ethernet. No matter what I return or where I redirect, there is no poup automatically opening like it is for Wifi.

Is osx even capable of Captive Portal when using USB to Ethernet adapters? Or do I need a special apple adapter for that?

By the way, I already got it working on Windows machines with USB to Ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about "USB to Ethernet"-adapters regarding captive portals. Having a "special Apple adapter" will not help you in that regard.

You must find the error in your system somewhere else.

Actually I'm not even sure that Mac OS X looks for captive portals on *wired* networks. As far as I recall, the Captive Network Assistant is only activated for *wireless* networks. Your USB adapter would count as a wired network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - and yes, that's exactly what I'm afraid of. Windows supports Captive Portal even in wired mode - for osx, I can't find anything about that. Everyone is only telling about wispr which is definitely a wireless thingy. The request that I'm seeing (http://init-p01st.push.apple.com/bag) doesn't seem to be related to the Captive Portal but more about iCloud / iMessage.

Comment: Yes, init-p01st.push.apple.com is used for Push Notifications (can be any type of notification for various apps, not just iMessages). It hasn't got anything to do with captive portals.

Comment: Is this still the case (that OSX doesn't support looking for captive portals on wired networks)?